# How to provide free access to my paid Extension for specific accounts?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have paid Chrome Extension and want to provide free access to it for my friends, how can I do this?

*I've read Chrome Web Store in-app payments documentation, but there is no answer for my question*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > You can add gmail id(s) from the **Chrome Developer Dashboard** section and your friend's can install the Chrome extension by *Signin* with their gmail id:

Here are the Steps:
1) Login your [Chrome DashBoard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard)
2) Add the comma seperated gmail id(s) from the field
    a) **Basic look of Chrome Dashboard**: Your Developer Account -> Edit your Tester Accounts
    b) **Updated look of Chrome Dashboard**: Settings -> Trusted Tester Accounts
3) Click on Save.

Once the Tester account will get added, your friend(s) can signin the Chrome Web Store with their gmail can install the Chrome Extension without paying.

[image]